# Error Notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have a `refresh button`, when i press it it `refreshes` my xml file and puts it in the `tableview`, what i want is, when i dont have connection to my xml file, i want it to show me a pop up that tells me there is no conntion to the server.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"No Connection" delegate:refreshButton cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

hope you can help

any idea how ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the return code from your http request. If it is a code that signifies no network connection, you can show the alert view.

I suggest using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) if you aren't already. It lets you set failure blocks that will execute when the request doesn't complete successfully.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is no longer being developed.  Might I suggest https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking instead.

Comment: @cpjolicoeur do u have any source, where this is stated?